# Phonegap+ jquery mobile windows phone 8 app slow loading local html file

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

we are developing a phonegap with jquery mobile app for windows phone 8. We are facing problem. We are getting blank black screen between page transitions of htmls. All the htmls are local, no internet required. Each page takes hell lot of time to load. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use the jqm. The library is very heavy and not many phones today can handle it easily. An alternative would be to use sencha touch.

If you know Backbonejs then just go for it. If you dont know backbone or you dont want to use Sencha, then just use plain Javascript. You can do everyting you need with just plain JS.

Comment: But my problem is that the app is already built and released in app store and play store. I am trying for windows phone 8 now. Changing the whole framework is like building the app from scratch again. Is there any other solution?? All html pages are taking hell lot of time to load.

Comment: can you post some code of how you change page. also have you switched  off all the page transition animations?

Comment: Sorry i cant post the code snippet bcoz of some copyright issue. But yeah i have switched off all page transitions. Mine is multi page structure and i am using window.location.href for switching between pages.

Comment: I don't understand why you need jquery mobile, if you don't even use jQuery.mobile.changePage() function for page changing. Also do you use any animations? If you do, then try to use css animations instead of js.

Comment: I am using jquery mobile only for css properties like left panel, header, footer, list, tabs navigation and page container properties. I am not using any kind of transitions at all. In every page loading, the page has to load for deviceready to be called, that's why its's taking lot of time.

Comment: Very hard to say something without seeing the code. One thing I can advise is to use a nice loader gif during page transition to make it less uglier.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with the loader option.